# Why Golang was chosen to implement ethereum protocol?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, golang, clients, protocol

I know there are many implementations of the Ethereum protocol, i.e. the first implementation in Python, or other implementations using C++, C#, and Java. As [go-ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/) has gained lots of attention recently, other implementations such as [aleth](https://github.com/ethereum/aleth) have deprecated or lost their [market share](https://www.ethernodes.org/).
I've experience with C++, and I know -despite all its complexity- it is flexible and powerful enough to use as a blockchain implementation language. So, the question is why a new language -compared to its counterparts- such as Go was chosen for re-implementing Ethereum? What specific feature does it have that makes it a suitable choice for such a purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wanted to have several implementations to minimize the security risks. Initially there were implementation in C++, python, go, rust, etc. There were plans for writing implementations in java, and javascript.

For different circumstances some projects lost developers, or they never got enough developers. They started to lag behind in features and fixing bug, so go-ethereum become the standard because there wasn't actively mantained alternatives.

More recently besu, a client written in java, emerged from ethereum enterprise initiatives.

If you have the necessary skill try asking the Ethereum Foundation. They used to have fund available for writing alternative implementations.